# What features distinguish Postbox from Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, postbox

I started using Postbox Express because it supports Omnifocus, but now I'm eyeing Postbox itself, which is a $39.95 application. Given that it's a variant of Thunderbird, what features does Postbox provide for that $40 that Thunderbird 3 does not?

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, Postbox is a Cocoa application. Thunderbird isn't. So you can take advantage of some features you can only do in Cocoa applications. Such as pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to get an inline definition of a word. And in my opinion, Postbox looks one heck of a lot better than Thunderbird.

Comment: I just tried it, it doesn't work. Popup menus and the toolbar aren't native/Cocoa either.